# PineScript strategy exit not exiting at profit level but at candle close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to understand why my strategy will exit at the close of the candle rather than when it actually hits my Profit Level. I've tried using the strategy close and strategy exit but I seem to be getting the same results.

[TP not executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Ydd.png)

My script uses a function to define the 4 stages of my trades (no position, open position, TP1 hit, trailing stop). Once I have the right condition to open an order, I use the Strategy entry function. The exit logic validates if I have an open position (stage 1) and creates the TP limit order and stop loss order. Once TP1 is hit, we move to stage 2 which brings my stop to Break Even. Finally, stage 3 is a trailing stop

```
getCurrentStage() =>
    var stage = 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0 
        stage := 0
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
    else if stage == 1 and curProfitInPts() >= tp1
        stage := 2
    else if stage == 2 //and curProfitInPts() >= tp1
        stage := 3
    stage



// ==== ENTRY LOGIC ==== //

if OpenLong and strategy.position_size == 0 //startLongTrade and EntryinSession and strategy.opentrades < 1 and ha_close[0] > ha_open[0]
    strategy.entry("ENTER LONG", strategy.long)

 
if OpenShort and strategy.position_size == 0 //startShortTrade and EntryinSession and strategy.opentrades < 1 and ha_close[0] < ha_open[0]
    strategy.entry("ENTER SHORT", strategy.short)


// === EXIT LOGIC === //

float trailOffsetLevel = na
float profitLevel = activateTrailingOnThirdStep ? calcTrailingAmountLevel(TrailingP) : calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp1)
trailOffsetLevelTmp = calcTrailingOffsetLevel(TrailingP, tp1)
float stopLevel = na

curStage = getCurrentStage()


if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(sl)
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.exit("Exit", "ENTER LONG", qty_percent = 50, limit = profitLevel, comment = "50% TP") //Add TP
        strategy.exit("Exit", "ENTER LONG", stop = stopLevel, comment = "SL") //SL CONDITION
       
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.exit("Exit", "ENTER SHORT", qty_percent = 50, limit = profitLevel, comment = "50% TP")
        strategy.exit("Exit", "ENTER SHORT", stop = stopLevel, comment = "SL")
        

else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(0)
    if strategy.position_size > 0 
        strategy.close("ENTER LONG", comment = "Close 50%" ,qty_percent = 50, immediately = true)
        
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close("ENTER SHORT", comment = "Close 50%", qty_percent = 50, immediately = true)

else if curStage == 3
    
    if activateTrailingOnThirdStep
        stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(-tp1)
        trailOffsetLevel := trailOffsetLevelTmp
        strategy.exit("Exit", stop = stopLevel, trail_points = TrailingP, trail_offset = TrailingOff, comment = "Trailing Stop")
    else
        stopLevel := yhat1
        
        if strategy.position_size > 0 and CloseLong
            strategy.close("ENTER LONG", comment = "Close balance")
            
        else if strategy.position_size < 0 and CloseShort
            strategy.close("ENTER SHORT", comment = "Close balance")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Close 50%` is coming from `strategy.close()`.

> It is a command to exit from the entry with the specified ID. If there
> were multiple entry orders with the same ID, all of them are exited at
> once. If there are no open entries with the specified ID by the moment
> the command is triggered, the command will not come into effect. **The
> command uses market order**. Every entry is closed by a separate
> market order.

As the documentation states, it uses market orders. That's why it closes your position on candle close.

You should be using `strategy.exit()` instead.

Comment: Thank you that worked for my first take profit but introduced a strange behaviour. Now the stop loss seems mixed up with the TP as per the following snapshot https://www.tradingview.com/x/hSZsbO4Y/

Comment: Your code is over complicated. You shouldn't be working with that many ifs and calling `strategy.exit()` and `strategy.close()` conditionally. Instead, call them in the global scope and modify your TP and SL prices conditionally.